# Problem in Add days to Date Problem in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2019. I have done coding to add days in date and the date is in Label1. When I execute the code on my local system, it works fine. But when I execute the code on the server, it adds days wrongly to the date.

My code is shown here:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
         Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
     }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Label1.Text).AddDays(1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Executing the code on server returns the following output - for example today date is 09/07/2020, and I get this output:

- On clicking button :    `7/10/2020`
- On clicking button :    `11/7/2020`
- On clicking button :    `08/11/2020`
- On clicking button :    `12/08/2020`
- On clicking button :    `09/12/2020`
- On clicking button :    `13/09/2020`

Comment: You need to check the Regional and Language Options configuration on the server  .

Comment: You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` for reverse conversion.

Answer (score 1):

It works on my machine because I'm french...

What is your system locale settings and date format?

You should save the DateTime in a private var and use it instead of the label to increment to avoid conversion problems:

```
private DateTime Label1DateTime;

private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    Label1DateTime = DateTime.Now;
    Label1.Text = Label1DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
  }
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Label1DateTime = Label1DateTime.AddDays(1);
  Label1.Text = TheDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Now it should work on any system.

---

On WinForms, you can also use the Tag property of the label if you don't want to create a class member...

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Label1.Tag = DateTime.Now;
  Label1.Text = ((DateTime)Label1.Tag).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if ( Label1.Tag is DateTime )
  { 
    var date = ((DateTime)Label1.Tag);
    date = date.AddDays(1);
    Label1.Tag = date;
    Label1.Text = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but problem not solved now it is displaying date 01/01/2001 and does add days.

Comment: Perhaps the var is not initialized because of the `if (!IsPostBack)`... If it does not work by removing this test or using `private DateTime Label1DateTime = DateTime.Now;` to be sure to have something, could you indicate a link to the new code file, please?

Comment: sorry this date displaying 1/2/0001 12:00:00

Comment: Hence that's it: the date is not initialized checking IsPostBack... even with your original code.

Comment: If this is webforms which it looks like private variables are not preserved during postback.

Comment: Indeed, that must be it because of the Form_Load and IsPostBack...

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the culture of the thread in which the program runs to get the same behavior on all machines.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentculture

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the date format ("dd/MM/yyyy"), then the problem is solved.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{

```
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime dateonly = dt.Date;
            Label1.Text = dateonly.ToString().Replace(" 12:00:00 AM","");
           
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Label1.Text).AddDays(1).ToString().Replace(" 12:00:00 AM", "");
        
    }
```